# Api Integrity Issues

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play-integrity-api

I am migrating my app from Google play safety net api to Integrity api, but getting below error from api-

When i using setCloudProjectNumber(idProjectNumber) retrieve :
Integrity API error (-8): The calling app is making too many requests to the API and hence is throttled.
Retry with an exponential backoff

when i remove setCloudProjectNumber(idProjectNumber) retrieve :
Integrity API error (-12): Unknown internal Google server error.
Retry with an exponential backoff.

Please I need To know Why this error is retrieve
note :The app has been uploaded To Google play using SafetyNet

Comment: Did you see the message? "retry with exponential backoff" --- what happens when you do that? In case you don't know what that means: retry, if it fails wait e.g., 1s, retry, wait 2s, then 4s, the 8s... until it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably haven't set up the API in the Play Console. From https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#apps-on-google-play, see "In the Play Console, navigate to the Release section of the left menu. Go to Setup > App integrity. Select the Integrity API tab to get started."

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something of a rate-limit active for maximum API requests.
I have no knowledge about the Playstore services since a long time so is there any?